# Is it possible to set the name of one variable to the contents of another?

Tags: java

Say I have a variable `test` with the value `example`. I want to make a new variable that is called the value of `test`, so the new variable would be called `example`.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Can you describe why you want this, and what you would do with the variable once created? Sounds more like a use for a Map than a regular Java variable.

Comment: No you can't do that. That's like meta programming.

Comment: You can simulate this by using a `Map<String, Object> variables`. Example: `Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>(); String test = "example"; variables.put("example", test)`;

Comment: The answer is that no this can't be done nor should it be attempted. Variable names are not as important as you might think and almost don't exist in compiled code. Instead it's references that matter, and these can be associated with Strings via a Map (as @LuiggiMendoza notes above).

Comment: My intended use for this is as follows:

I'm making a chat server, and I an storing all of the usernames in an ArrayList of the class `User` (which I made). I wanted to name each variable of User the name the user chose, because then it would be easier to remove from the list later on (i.e. `UserList.remove([name]);`

I guess I'll store arbitrary variable names like `user`, and then to remove, have a `for` loop looking for the User.name property. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Again, use a Map. Please look at A.R.S.'s answer (1+) and follow it.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958848/is-it-possible-to-name-a-variable-using-a-variable-in-java?rq=1, and many others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible in Java. Variable names cannot be set at runtime. However, you can mimic this using a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps `String` identifiers to values.

```
String test = "example";
...
Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
vars.put(test, "...");
```